# C# http request mtls external private key

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, smartcard, mtls

I want to address an api via C# that requires mtls authentication.

The difficulty here is that the private key of the certificate is stored on a smartcard. This means that I only have the public X509 certificate in .net and I can create RSA Sh256 signatures on the smartcard with which the mtls connection need to established.

Is there any possibility in .NET to override the function for the TLS client signature in the http request lib?

Thank You!

Comment: Please clarify why you'd need that. Usually the private key is still associated with the certificate when it is used in the Microsoft way of handling keys / certs, even if the cert  can be stored in the memory and the private key remains on the smart card. Or do you need to somehow change the algorithm used for signing? Downloading the cert and just creating a certificate from that is not the way forward, you need to use CMS functionality to represent cert / key / algorithm.

Comment: Thank you Maarten for the quick feedback. There are no drivers for the smartcard that Windows supports directly. I can create RSA PSS signatures manually with c# and java using APDU commands. This also works and in Java I can establish the MTLS connection with my own SignatureSpi class by implementing the enginSign method myself.

In C# I can already read the certificate from the smartcard and would now like to pass a method to the HttpClient in which I implement the signature function for client authentication myself. Thank You!